# What exactly is "Error] name lookup of 'N' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]"?

Tags: c, barcode

I just wrote a program that calculates the EAN or UPC's last digit. and here is the process:

1.Calculate the sum of the digits in the odd numbered positions and multiply this sum by 3(Even numbers)

2.Calculate the sum of the digits in the even numbered positions(Odd numbers)

3. Add the results of the first sum to the second sum and subtract 1 from the total.
4. Calculate the remainder when divided by 10.
5. Subtract the remainder from 9

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 

{

    int A[12], sumEven, total;
    int sumOdd = 0;

    printf("Enter your 12-digits number:");
    scanf("%s", &A);

    for(int N = 0; N < 12; N += 2);
    {
    sumOdd = sumOdd + A[N];
    }

    for(int L = 1; L < 12; L += 2);
    {
    sumEven += A[L];
    }

    total = (sumEven * 3 + sumOdd) - 1;
    total %= 10;
    total = 9 - total;

    printf("The digit is:%d", total);

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the error messages:

[Error] name lookup of 'N' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

[Note] (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)

[Error] name lookup of 'L' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

I guess that it has something to do with my loops, but I don't know where exactly because I have seen similar usage of loop before. Please tell me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally put `;` at the end of your `for` loops

```
for(int N = 0; N < 12; N += 2); // <-- note the semicolon here
    {
    sumOdd = sumOdd + A[N];
    }
```

So this code part

```
    {
    sumOdd = sumOdd + A[N];
    }
```

is out of scope of your `for` loop where `N` is not defined. Just remove those semicolons at the end of your `for` loops to get rid of that error. Note that there are other problems with your code, but this is the cause of this particular error.

Comment: Good spot. That puts `N` and `L` out of scope.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. Yes exactly.

Comment: But you should make it clear that you mean the semicolons which are not shown in this answer.

Comment: But you have shown correct lines, not the incorrect ones (and there is a lot more wrong with the code, such as `int sumEven` has not been initialised).

Comment: Oh... Sorry that I didn't notice that. Sorry to bother you guys with such a stupid mistake

Comment: @WeatherVane While you are not wrong the question is about the cause of that particular error code, but i will edit it in a second to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many faults with the code:

- The loop controls end in `;` which makes them a complete loop, and the control variables `N` and `L` used in the next code blocks are out of scope.
- The array is the wrong type, and is too short to hold 12 digits (with the null termintator).
- The `scanf` statement should drop the `&`, and restrict the input length to prevent buffer overflow.
- The data entered is character digits. If you subtract `'0'` that converts to the numeric value.
- One variable `int sumEven` was not initialised.

I amended and commented where changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char A[13];                                 // change type, and length
    int sumEven = 0;                            // initialise
    int sumOdd = 0;
    int total;

    printf("Enter your 12-digits number:");
    scanf("%12s", A);                           // restrict the length and remove &

    for(int N = 0; N < 12; N += 2)              // remove ;
    {
        sumOdd = sumOdd + A[N] - '0';           // ASCII adjustment
    }

    for(int L = 1; L < 12; L += 2)              // remove ;
    {
        sumEven = sumEven + A[L] - '0';         // ASCII adjustment
    }

    total = (sumEven * 3 + sumOdd) - 1;
    total %= 10;
    total = 9 - total;

    printf("The digit is:%d", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Eraklon said you should not put that `;` after for loops .`for(...);` this is wrong.

also note your `sumEven` is uninitialized that will probably cause crash.